# What is this conversion called?

Tags: c++, terminology

Is there a name or a term for this type of conversion in the c++ community?
Has anyone seen this conversion be referred to as "implicit conversion"?

```
class ALPHA{};

class BETA{
    public:
        operator ALPHA(){return alpha;}
    private:
        ALPHA alpha;
};

void func(ALPHA alpha){}

int main(){
    BETA beta;
    func(beta);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normally called a conversion function. It isn't an implicit conversion per se, but does allow implicit conversion to the target type.

Edit: just checked to be sure -- §12.3.2 of the standard uses the phrase "conversion function".

Edit2: I checked in the official standard, which isn't (at least supposed to be) freely available (though you can buy it from the [ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38110) or most member standards organizations such as [ANSI](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=BS+ISO%2fIEC+14882%3a2003), [BSI](http://shop.bsigroup.com/en/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000030116778), etc.) A lot of people prefer to save the money and use the [final committee draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf), which is free.

Comment: where did you check that, can  you post the link?

Answer (score 1):

That is commonly called a *conversion operator*.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit conversion is often referred to as *coercion*.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `func(beta)` object `beta` is *implicitly converted* to type `ALPHA`. This is only possible because you have implemented `operator ALPHA()`.